# Spring Boot - Only secure actuator endpoints

Tags: security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using Spring Boot (`1.3.0`) with Jersey (pom dependencies: `spring-boot-starter-jersey`, `spring-boot-starter-actuator`, `spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-security`).

I have a Jersey endpoint (see below) which is really simple:

```
@Component
@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World !";
    }
}
```

I have enabled Spring Boot Actuator by setting a particular path for Spring MVC url (`server.servlet-path=/system`), as explained in [Spring Boot guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-actuator-with-jersey).
Thanks to `spring-boot-starter-security`, Actuator endpoints are secured via basic authentification.

My problem here is that `/helloworld` is also secured, but I would like to leave it unsecured.

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

You have to configure the settings in yaml/properties file like below -

```
server:
  port: 8080
  context-path: /MyApplication

security:
   user:
       name: admin
       password: secret
   basic:
       enabled: false

management:
   context-path: /actuator
   security:
             enabled: true
```

So, for your application security is disabled but is enabled for actuator endpoints. Make sure you don't configure username/password under management security otherwise it will not work.

Comment: As of spring 1.5.4 you do not need to set any specific `context-path` in the .yml. I could do with setting `security.basic.enabled=false` and `management.security.enabled=true`, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @MartinHansen Ditto.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `security.user.name` property together with `management.security.role` to your configuration such as `application.properties` or configuration from spring cloud config center and search the random password in startup logs. Of course ,you can also add password in `bootstrap.yml` to use what you are specified.

Comment: `bootstrap.yml` is a Spring Cloud feature. It should be `application.properties` or `application.yml` with plain Spring Boot.

Comment: You are right, `bootstrap.yml` is not generic enough.

Comment: You don't answer the question :) I'm able to secure actuator (http://myDomain/system) but not leave other endpoints unsecured (http://myDomain/myURI).

Comment: Usually actuator will be integrated into the other project such as spring mvc project. If your project contains other endpoint not controller that should be different. Would your please publish more information about your project's structure ? Such as other spring modules.

Comment: As what I know spring security would not treat actuator different from your uri. But it's reasonable to change actuator's port even address or disable it's security and leave it to firewall or just isolate it with different networks.

Comment: Change actuator's port don't solve the problem, `/helloworld` is still not available without basic authentification.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But in my mind, the actuator is usually used for maintenance, it's should not be published together with your business URIs to common users even to public. So you can change your mind for this scenario.

Comment: Even if I change the port (and you are right, for security reasons, it's a good practice), all uri are handled the same way so it does't solve my problem.